# If statement calculation

Tags: sql, if-statement, sum

I need to sum the data in "amount" column only if the data in the "type column" = Gross Incurred Loss, Overpayment Loss, salvage and subrogation. Do you know what if statement I can use in the code below to accomplish this?

```
select        total.*     
from          (
select        p.policyNum,
                            p.stateID,
                            p.effectiveDate as date,
                            p.premiumTotal,
              a.claimFreeDiscount,
                            a.homeownerDiscount,
                            a.policyZip,
                            mb.claimnumber,
                            **if .....**
                            sum(mb.amount)     as totalclm 
                            
                from aggressive.dbo.Policy                                                  as p
              inner join Aggressive.dbo.Auto                                          as a  
                on p.policyID = a.policyID
                      left join MicrosoftPowerBI.dbo.ClaimTransactionDetail                as mb
                on p.policyid = mb.policyid
                where p.stateID = 74 and
                p.companyID = 10 and
                p.status =1
                                                                                                                                             
                group by p.policynum,
                         p.stateID,
                               p.effectiveDate,
                                 p.premiumTotal,
                 a.claimFreeDiscount,
                             a.homeownerDiscount,
                               a.policyZip,
                                 mb.claimnumber)                                                
                                                                                                   as total
          order by total.totalclm desc
```

Comment: That code looks like SQL - please add a tag to your question for the database you're using.

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesn’t have IF statements, it has CASE statements.

Just use a CASE statement to create a column that has the required value if the type column is in the list else it has a value of zero - and then sum that column